# Text to speech using python on mac m2 chip

Tags: voice, python-3.11, pyttsx3

Not a pro with python but trying to build stuff to add to my resume. Im following a tutorial on building a "JARVIS". I'm getting an error when trying to execute:

```
[Code issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN7Mm.jpg)
```

I have tried to reinstall pyttsx3 and speech recognition. I am on 3.11 because i was having issues with 3.12 getting pyaudio to install. right now i am stuck. I used Chatgpt to help me solve it but nothing was getting me anywhere. I also ran across some stuff on here but nothing was pointing me in the right step.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here: `engine = pyttsx3.init()`

You need to specify which driver module to load: in order to do this, replace the line with `engine = pyttsx3.init('nsss')` as 'nsss' is the module for MacOS computers

more info: https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html

Comment: i did that in the past trying to ts, but always got this as a response: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fallenangel/Desktop/JARVIS/JARVIS", line 3, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init(nsss)
                          ^^^^
NameError: name 'nsss' is not defined

Comment: Try espeak? I’m not sure